# Excel VBA to extract body of outlook email - unable to read html inner textemails

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to loop through all emails in a folder called Aberdeen. My attached code works on text emails, but it does not read HTML emails.

I have included in the code looking for a string from the email subject to determine what code to run as each code I require to be extracted is in a different format.

I was also trying to find a way to extract the first word before space, second word etc. as at present my code just copies each line of text. I was hoping to add something like `sheet2.range("A"&x).value = FindWord(abody(j),1)` for first word. wit `x` being next empty row sheet2.

The extracted data looks like this:

```
0C2007 ---------- HP-1373CMP B73G 13925 10925 11/25/2018 12:04:13 
0C204C ---------- HP-1539CMP B738 ----- ----- 11/25/2018 17:13:30 
0C208D CMP229 HP-1830CMP B738 37000 37000 11/25/2018 17:02:05 
0C2094 CMP236 HP-1833CMP B738 37000 37000 11/25/2018 11:06:56 
0C20A4 CMP235 HP-1836CMP B738 36000 36000 11/25/2018 21:19:35
```

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub EmailText()
    Dim oHTML As MSHTML.HTMLDocument: Set oHTML = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim ObjOutlook As Object
    Dim MyNamespace As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Long
    Dim abody() As String
    Dim strSubject As String

    Dim x

    Set ObjOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")        
    Set MyNamespace = ObjOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    On Error Resume Next

    For i = 1 To MyNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("Aberdeen").Items.Count
        strSubject = MyNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("Aberdeen").Items(i).Subject
        If strSubject Like "*Berdeen*" Then GoTo Aberdeen
        If strSubject Like "*KPGD*" Then GoTo KPGD
        If strSubject Like "*Canada*" Then GoTo Canada
        If strSubject Like "*Blandford*" Then GoTo Blandford
        If strSubject Like "*Macap*" Then GoTo Macapa
        If strSubject Like "*Netherlands*" Then GoTo Netherlands
        GoTo notfound

Aberdeen: 'This email format is in html and I think it needs to get the code from html inner text
        abody = Split(MyNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("Aberdeen").Items(i).Body, vbCrLf)        
        For j = 0 To UBound(abody)
            If Len(abody(j)) > 60 And Len(abody(j)) < 68 Then Sheet1.Cells(650000, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = (abody(j))
        Next

        MyNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("Aberdeen").Items(i).Move MyNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("Aberdeen_Complete")
        GoTo comp


KPGD:
        abody = Split(MyNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("Aberdeen").Items(i).Body, vbCrLf)
        For j = 0 To UBound(abody)
            If Len(abody(j)) > 60 And Len(abody(j)) < 68 Then Sheet1.Cells(650000, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = (abody(j))
        Next

        MyNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("Aberdeen").Items(i).Move MyNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("Aberdeen_Complete")
        GoTo comp


Canada:
        For j = 0 To UBound(abody)    
            If Len(abody(j)) > 60 And Len(abody(j)) < 68 Then Sheet1.Cells(650000, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = (abody(j))
        Next

        MyNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("Aberdeen").Items(i).Move MyNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("Aberdeen_Complete")
        GoTo comp


Blandford:
        For j = 0 To UBound(abody) 
            If Len(abody(j)) > 60 And Len(abody(j)) < 68 Then Sheet1.Cells(650000, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = (abody(j)) 
        Next

        MyNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("Aberdeen").Items(i).Move MyNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("Aberdeen_Complete")
        GoTo comp


Macapa:
        For j = 0 To UBound(abody)
            If Len(abody(j)) > 80 Then Sheet1.Cells(650000, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = (abody(j)) 
        Next

        MyNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("Aberdeen").Items(i).Move MyNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("Aberdeen_Complete")


Netherlands:
        For j = 0 To UBound(abody)
            If Len(abody(j)) > 54 And Len(abody(j)) < 68 Then Sheet1.Cells(650000, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = (abody(j))   
        Next

        MyNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("Aberdeen").Items(i).Move MyNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("Aberdeen_Complete")
        GoTo comp


notfound:
comp:
    Next

    Set ObjOutlook = Nothing
    Set MyNamespace = Nothing
End Sub


Function FindWord(Source As String, Position As Integer)
    Dim xcount
    Dim arr() As String
    arr = VBA.Split(Source, " ")
    xcount = UBound(arr)
    If xcount < 1 Or (Position - 1) > xcount Or Position < 0 Then
        FindWord = ""
    Else
        FindWord = arr(Position - 1)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Some notes: Remove `On Error Resume Next` this line only hides all error messages but the errors still occur. If you cannot see them you cannot fix them. Before doing anything else remove it and fix your errors! • Using `Goto` is a very bad practice replace it with a `Select Case` statement (google for tutorials on that).

Comment: thanks for the update. it does not come up with an error when i remove on error resume next , it is just not seeing any text in the body because it is in html format.

Comment: can you show me an example of how I can incorporate Select Case into my code please. Cant get my head around it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to work out how to split the fields using the split option code is below.
Thanks for looking at this and your comments.

```
    KPGD:
      abody = Split(MyNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("Aberdeen").Items(i).Body, 
    vbCrLf)

   For j = 0 To UBound(abody)

   If Len(abody(j)) > 60 And Len(abody(j)) < 68 Then
   Sheet1.Cells(650000, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = (abody(j))
   Sheet2.Cells(650000, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Split(abody(j), " ")(0)
   Sheet2.Cells(650000, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Split(abody(j), " ")(1)
   Sheet2.Cells(650000, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Split(abody(j), " ")(2)
   Sheet2.Cells(650000, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Split(abody(j), " ")(3)
   Sheet2.Cells(650000, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Split(abody(j), " ")(6)
   End If
   Next
   MyNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("Aberdeen").Items(i).Move 
   MyNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("Aberdeen_Complete")
   GoTo comp
```